# current_user set to nil on redirect (session lost?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, rspec, devise, capybara

### Configuration

Webpacker application using `Rails 5.1` with `Vue.js 2.5`

I've been trying to diagnose this bug for 3 days now and I am at my wits end. I've started to add system tests using `Capybara` using standard `selenium-webdriver`.

Problems occur when I am trying to access authenticatable routes, for example, user settings:

```
RSpec.describe 'home page', type: :system do
  before(:context) do
    WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
  end

  after do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end

  context 'when logged in' do
    context 'as an average user' do

      before do
        @profile = create(:profile)
        @user = @profile.user
        @user.update(confirmed_at: Time.now)

        login_as(@user, scope: :user)
      end

      it 'redirects to Account Settings page after pressing Account Settings' do
        visit '/'

        find('.profile-menu').hover
        find('.settings').click

        expect(page).to have_content 'Account Settings'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

this is not a link and is handled in my `.vue` file, which just redirects to the route I need `location.href = "/users/edit";`

When I am on the root page, I am signed in, `current_user` returns the user and all is great. But as soon as I press that link, at some point it gets reset as I get redirected to the standard `Devise` Login page.

If I directly go to that page `visit '/users/edit`, but `current_user` is set and its all fine.

This is my test devise setup:

```
require 'devise'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
end
```

Let me know if you need some extra information, I think I've provided all the crucial bits but could have missed something.

Comment: Are you sure the `@user.update(confirmed_at: Time.now)` is succeeding?  Also are you calling `Warden::test_reset!` in an after block?

Comment: Yup, it's confirmed and I do `test_reset!` after each example. The `current_user` just becomes `nil` @ThomasWalpole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed this issue. I've tried a couple things mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49248170/2308531). As far as I can tell, what fixed it was fixing my configuration from:

```
 RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
 end
```

to

```
 RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :system
 end
```

This also allowed me to drop:

```
  after(:each) do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end
```

in all my tests. I've run quite a few tests and they don't fail anymore, so I am for now assuming this has been indeed fixed.