# How to have factory only create data one time for all tests in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here is a little simplified version of my code:

```
frozen_string_literal: true
RSpec.describe MyObject do
  let!(:my_object)  { create(:my_object, name: 'This Name') }
  let!(:my_ojbect_2) { create(:my_object_2, obj: my_object) }

  describe '#my_data' do
    subject { my_object.my_data }

    context 'when a' do
      ...
      ...

      it { is_expected.to eq expected_value }
    end

    context 'when b' do
      ...
      ...
      it { is_expected.to eq expected_value }
    end

    context 'when' do
      ...
      ...
      it { byebug }
    end
  end
end
```

When the test stopped at the byebug, I noticed that my_object was created multiple times in the database. Is there a way to have my_object only create one time?

Comment: `let` is evaluated per example by design. What you're looking to do is usually not a good idea as you're setiing yourself up for flapping tests due to residual state between tests. If you really want to do it anyways you can use `before(:all)` to setup an instance variable instead. You should also consider if you really need to save the record to the db - use `build_stubbed` instead were possible.

Comment: I agree with @max. You want each test case to be a clean slate. What are you trying to accomplish by making it just once? Performance?

Comment: Thanks. I tried `build_stubbed` but it didn't work. Also, I tried the `before(:all)`, but I ran into issues since I am using some of the variables inside  the it statements.

Comment: @pixelearth I have a raw query that is something like this `( SELECT id FROM my_object WHERE my_object.name = 'This Name' LIMIT 1 )`. Since my_object is created two times, it is grabbing the wrong one.  If I limited to only being created one time, my problem would go away. The problem is myobject is referenced in multiple places.

Comment: I think you don't have this set up to be cleaned between tests. You need to clean your db: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner

Comment: test config can get complicated with factories, fixtures, transactional fixtures, etc. I always just use the database cleaner.

Comment: @pixelearth Thanks the database cleaner wasn't running between tests. If you don't mind can you post that as an answer so I can give you credit since that was the correct answer?

Comment: Using `database_cleaner` has not been needed since RSpec 3.7 was released which was a long time ago. You're of course free to use it if you feel like it but in this case it really sounds like the wrong answer to the wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multiple copies of test objects are persisting between tests this creates huge problems for your tests, and they cannot be relied on.

You have to have a clean slate between tests. There are a number of ways to do this, but it can get complicated with factories, fixtures, transactional fixtures, etc.

I personally almost always end up using a database cleaner.

Have a look at  [Database Cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner)

Comment: Database cleaner isn't really needed in modern versions of Rails - I havent used it for years - RSpec generally works just fine with transactional fixtures.

Comment: I don't use fixtures personally, and often have issues with transaction-wrapped data in tests. Could be me, but I find the db cleaner useful.

Comment: You don't need to use fixtures, the point is really that rails gives a clean slate without needing db cleaner these days so it's less configuration. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49246124/544825